# Formatting MySQL date in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a noob to MySQL and have a question. How would I format the date taken from a column?

My code is `$row = $wpdb->get_results("select * from wp_miles");`

```
foreach ( $row as $row ) { echo "$row->mile_history on $row->date<BR>";}
```

it's obviously the `$row->date` I want to change from `2016-02-13` to `M j`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
  date("M j",strtotime($row->date));
```

Comment: I tried 'foreach ( $row as $row ) { echo "$row->mile_history on" . date(M j,$row->date) . "<BR>";}' and got ' Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'j' (T_STRING) in /home/nickgalgay/public_html/wp-content/themes/miletracker/mysqlecho.php on line 11'

Comment: You're missing the `strtotime` which is why it's not returning anything interesting.

Comment: Plus you're missing the quotes around `M J`

Comment: `foreach ( $row as $rowdata ) { echo "$row->mile_history on" . date("M j",strtotime($rowdata->date)) . "<BR>";}`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that directly in your MySQL query. Whether replacing the same field value or using another field name like "formattedDate".

```
"select *, date_format(date, '%b %e') AS date from wp_miles"
```

or as new field if you also need date field as date value in php but I don't prefer this method if you also need to use date as date value in php since it will return more data from the query.

```
"select *, date_format(date, '%b %e') AS formattedDate from wp_miles"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function in your query string: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %j') as date, ... FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked.

```
foreach ( $row as $row ) { echo "$row->mile_history on" . "&nbsp;" . date("M j",strtotime($row->date)) . "<BR>";}
```

I used Matts answer and had to change small things. Thanks Matt and everyone else for the help.

:)